# How can people procreate when the medieval period is cursed with invisibility?

Tags: magic, medieval, reproduction, invisibility

Set in the medieval time, overnight a giant meteorite strikes the pacific ocean  and then a bright green glow sweeps the entire globe turning all human invisible to mammalian sight! Note that this is an illusion whereby the mammalian brain refuses to recognise or register a human being regardless what s/he is wearing, I wonder how would people find mate and rise their young when they can't see each other?

Note: the condition is similar to human being blindness but much worst, the brain will experience excruciating pain when there is any attempt to trace out the silhouette of a person even the suggestion alone would bring about a concussion. Basically the brain develops a fear of sight of a human being including sketches of a hand or eyes, under a normal circumstances the mammalian brain filter out people which would otherwise had dire consequences.

Comment: Part of this is treating the condition like a form of hysterical blindness, while another part is describing as more like "unnoticeability" -- one is covered in an answer, the other is the end of humanity in less than one generation.  We can't answer until it's clarified which is intended.

Comment: Oh great, the *S.S. Bistromath*'s Somebody Else's Problem field is malfunctioning.

Comment: To clarify: you mean that the visual cortex is completely ignoring all people and anything they wear, and not the whole brain?

Comment: @Trioxidane: the brain will photoshop all the images one sees to leave out the human ;D

Comment: What does vision have to do with sex?

Comment: If any attempt, conscious or unconscious, to feel the shape of a human, causes pain, then every baby born will be outcast & the human race will be over.  Either that or some seriously high-quality headache medicines will be invented.  I don't think your premise is going to lead to much of a story.

Comment: @John  you need to get out more :-) .  Srsly, I know people who are very turned on by watching their partner, or by both partners watching porn while copulating

Comment: @user6760 You have a bigger problem than you think. If just knowing indirectly where a person is causes pain, then people can't have sex without immense pain. A person can easily figure out where a partner (and even parts of a partner like their limbs) are during intercourse based on other senses: touch, smell, etc. If even attempts to figure out someone's sillhouette indirectly cause pain this would definitely cause pain too. If people were just invisible life would...find a way, but in this case you have something much more serious.

Comment: Is this restricted to humans, or affects all mammals?

Comment: @Alexander: all mammals

Comment: You really need to specify how restrictive this is - if you can't touch without pain, game over. Even using a turkey baster to fertilize females would give rise to births where mom couldn't care for their babies, and would hear them crying until they saw the dead body. Otherwise all these answers are similar and good. Magic reptile fairy godmothers? Massive doses of opium (even that, probably wouldn't work)?

Comment: Does 'trace out the shape of the silhouette' refer to physical contact, or to creating/viewing artistic representations of people?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Humans regularly have sex without the lights on. Blind people do successfully bear and raise children -- even when both partners are blind. There is (demonstrably from real-world cases) no requirement to see a partner in order either to procreate or to raise children.

Comment: "Everyone looks the same in the dark"  <--   sarcastic humor that usually follows "Beer Goggles"

Comment: @Carl Witthoft: Unfortunately, not everyone feels the same, though :-)

Comment: Yup.  I exist.  My mother never saw my father.

Answer (score 7):

They would simply rely on other senses.

They can still hear each other.

They can still smell each other.

They can still touch each other.

How do you find a mate? You talk to people.

How do you raise your kids? Well, a lot more easily than an actual blind person. You may not be able to see your child, but you can hear them, you can reach out for them, and once you are holding them you can see everything else that you need.

Comment: How does this cover the phobic response from the second paragraph?  The way I read this, humans would unconsciously avoid one another, for fear of seeing/not-seeing.

Answer (score 4):

I assume only vision is blocked. As mentioned by Logan R. Kearsley and I read between the lines with Paul TIKI, they would still get relationships and such. After the first shock, they probably try to figure out ways to communicate and know who's who. Then build social interactions on that. I would imagine that for social interactions they will get something in front of their eyes that you can only partially look through. A cloth you can barely see through for example. This will give focus to other senses while not completely removing your ability to navigate. It would also reduce the anxiety people may get talking to visually disembodied voices and such. As said before, you can have "normal" relationships afterwards. Area's designated for whoring and other physisocial activities would get marked even better.

If everything and not just vision gets blocked, you have some options until a big roadblock. To seek out each other, music instruments would be perfect. They are items and not people and can be used for new forms of speaking. Melodies can help get messages across and types of instruments can assist in identifying things like station or their profession. Smell, taste and touch are out. Smell and taste are difficult to reproduce and convey, especially as it's generally difficult to have the correct area of effect. Touch is even more difficult. Clothes and such would be ignored, so maybe planting things on you that are so outlandish or far away from the body it wouldn't be seen as clothes is trickly and leads to a lot of difficulties explaining what is allowed and what isn't.
But the roadblock is the worst. A man can't climax without stimulation. How can that be if touch of the other is ignored? Save for inserting things, there are precious little options to still procreate. Humanity would be doomed.

Answer (score 4):

## "Life, Uh, Finds a Way"

I anticipate fewer changes than you think. Other answers have proven that people can have sex without seeing each other (given the cost of candles in your era, this was probably the norm). What about courtship? People tend to meet each other through shared activities. These activities will still exist. For example, medieval churches were very influential and not being able to look at other people wouldn't change the church's religious and social importance. I met my wife in the campus church. One of the first things I noticed about her was her beautiful singing voice. We started talking after church and at university events. Our story would be similar even if we hadn't been able to look at each other.

If looking at humans caused pain, they could wear some kind of face mask that still let them see where they were walking without letting them see other people. They'd also be able to read hymnals and use tools and whatnot. Just such a device exists in the modern world for student pilots who are learning to rely on their instruments.

[image: IFR hood]

Answer (score 3):

Population growth would falter, but not stop.

Remember, we have five senses to go along with all of the rest of our urges.  And love that goes along with procreation does not solely require sight.

Smell and Touch are what I'm mostly talking about here.  Hearing to a lesser degree, although that would be important for more long term arrangements

The Sense of smell lets us detect pheromones, and though we tend to mask them now, it would be important for the survival of the species if you can't see one another.

Touch is also, obviously, very arousing to most humans.  Heck, there are people who blindfold one another in the bedroom, so that won't interfere with the mechanics of the situation.

So to deal with the problem, maybe establish "mating centers".  You go into a building with rooms that keep you isolated, put on a blindfold, a potential partner comes in, also blindfolded, and then let touch and smell take it from there.

Another option might be elaborate costumes.  Think of Queen Amidala from Star Wars: The Phantom Menace.  She had the elaborate headdress and huge robes that totally altered her silhouette.  That could be enough to allow people to "see" each other.

The biggest problem will be with raising children.  If you can't actually look at the kid, it becomes very hard to take care of it.  Perhaps a blinder arrangement that forces one to only look at parts of the child instead of the whole kid.  It kind of depends on what you mean by not being able to look at another human.  If all you see is the hand, that is a very different silhouette than the whole person.

Comment: Make the elaborate costumes into a separate answer... I'd upvote that.

Comment: @SRM I though about it, but I didn't think I could flesh it out enough to be a really good one.

Answer (score 0):

So, if your brain will make you not see a person carrying a stone, I presume it would just make you see the stone levitating, while the person will be ignored. The person's clothes will be ignored as well, falling into the "the silhouette of a person" part. So where do we draw the line between a stone and a pair of trousers? At the silhouette?

Maybe I'm looking for loopholes, but if the problematic part is human silhouette, why not try to address that directly? My first thought was a full set of plate armour (probably made of something lightweight, cardboard maybe?). But that's probably still too human, so perhaps just a few cardboard boxes on which you write your name! (for recognition, I imagine people becoming much better at recognising others' handwriting quickly!) And just as well as you wouldn't see the human carrying the stone, you won't see the pair of arms sticking out of the box, driving your bus, fixing your road's potholes, typing at the desk next to yours, or doing their homework in your living room. But you'd still see the box, with a recognisable handwritten name (or drawn personal symbol or what not)!

Impractical? Oh, yes. Still better than not seeing where your co-workers or family members are at all? Definitely.

Answer (score 0):

There's so much wrong here. Mating, as others have noted, is no problem. Voices, smells, or carrying odd objects all make everyone's position visible when that's wanted.

It's the social aspects that are mind-boggling. I can go invisible just by taking off my clothing? Imagine the crime rate when people can hide from sight that easily. And frankly, mating isn't going to be a problem, but involuntary sex will be - strangers could ravish with impunity; you'd never know who did it. Not to mention the enabling effect on warfare. If you don't see attackers coming and you don't know who to retaliate against, war becomes the simplest way to get anything done. This is going to be a VERY nasty civilization.

Do people with very visual imaginations have problems running their hands over other people, because they can visualize the shape of what they are touching? Sex is possible without caressing (if less fun) but if you can't scoop up your child without passing out, that's a problem. Human development is affected when there is little or no physical contact. It's been tried (websearch Romanian Orphans) and it doesn't go well.

Disease might be a problem if you can't see who is sick and avoid them.

The premise is frankly weird, but the question you asked is the least of the problems it generates. Widespread invisibility will cause so much social damage that I don't think the reproductive rate is the problem. Other things will cause civilization-threatening problems first.